# No se logra abrir el archivo sonoro

Tags: pygame, audio

## Hola gente, miren, he aqui un bug:

```
# importing libraries
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
# creating surface

# size of the surf
Fondo_Widht = 400

Fondo_Height = 300

Fondo = pygame.display.set_mode((Fondo_Widht, Fondo_Height))

pygame.display.set_caption('Ejercicio de moviento en X')

# variables
posx, posy = 0, 0

runningProgram = True
pygame.mixer.Sound('Sinfonia n25') # aca ocurre el bug
```

## Este es el error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matim\Desktop\Aprendizajes\Python\Codigo Facillito\Ejercicio de movimiento.py", line 17, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.Sound('Sinfonia n25')
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'Sinfonia n25'*
```

El bug supongo que esta relacionado con el archivo 'Sinfonia n25'
No pareceria importarse, pero dentro del comando puse exactamente el mismo nombre que el archivo introducir el código aquí:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/136X6J7_IqoOPFogqzfAceVSlVJoz6ZA_/view?usp=sharing

¿Que ocurre?

Espero amablemente su respuesta, saludos!

Nota: por si le ha interesado el audio utilizado, es la sinfonia n25 de Mozart, uno de los compositores de musica clasica mas talentosos, desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: Si te fijas en el link que enviaste, el archivo se llama Sinfonia n25.mp3. Como mencioné en mi respuesta, el nombre del archivo que colocaste en el código está mal porque falta la extensión, en este caso, el .mp3

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer te falta la extensión del archivo en la ruta al archivo. 
El código de Python necesita saber el formato del archivo está cargando porque el audio se codifica de manera distinta si es, por ejemplo, `.wav`, `.mp3` o `.ogg`.

Tu código incluye:

```
pygame.mixer.Sound('Sinfonia n25')
```

Como se puede ver en link al archivo fuente que colocaste, el nombre completo del archivo es `Sinfonia n25.mp3`. Por lo tanto, el código correcto debería escribirse así:

```
pygame.mixer.Sound('Sinfonia n25.mp3')
```

Asumiendo que el archivo esté en directorio del modulo que estás ejecutando; si no, deberás ingresar la ruta o *path* completo al archivo (Ej. `'C:/Sinfonia n25.mp3'`) o relativo (Ej. `'./data/Sinfonia n25.mp3'`)

Comment: Si tienes más información puedes editar tu pregunta, o agregar comentarios comentarios estaré atento.

Comment: Hola Vichoko, mire: recientemente he probaod espeificar el directorio y formato del archivo. Ahora el juego cambio: me sale el siguiente bug:                       '[]unicode error]'unicodeescape' codec can;t decode bytes in positon 2-4: truncated \UXXXXXXX escape.                                                                Igual, gracias por ayudarme, saludos !